# Blazor Wasm Hosted Mixed with Blazor Server Pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to be able to mix and match pages in my app between Web Assembly
(WASM) and Server to best suit the application.  eg. for pages that need to be highly secure or protect IP, I want to use Server pages, for other pages that I would like to offload workload to the client for performance or other reasons, I'll use WASM.

My plan was to use a Blazor Web Assembly hosted project, with the WASM pages hosted from the Client project and Server pages hosted from the Server project.

However, it has proven to be more complex than I anticipated to implement this and I wasn't able to find a write-up of this scenario.

The closest I could get was a series of posts and articles like this one
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/multiple-hosted-webassembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/multiple-hosted-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0) around hosting multiple web-assembly projects.  However, this only works for multiple WASM projects within a single solution.  It does not explain how to host Blazor Server pages from the Server project.

The above Microsoft link states that:

```
Optionally, the server project (MultipleBlazorApps.Server) can serve pages or views as a formal Razor Pages or MVC app.
```

I wanted to change this advice so that I could also serve Blazor Components from the Server project as well.  The following answer describes how I got it to work.  Please share any other comments / alternative methods if you have also tried to get this to work.

Comment: "Mixed" mode is messy.  On the assumption that your IP logic is code within your Application Domain, why not run that code within the API Server and make API requests from the WASM Presentation Domain?  Design is all about where you draw the Client/Server boundary.  I'll happily provide an example as an answer if you wish, but I don't want to preach to the converted!

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, I studied some of your repositories with interest, and they helped me understand the usage of MapWhen.  I thought that the use-case that I've documented here is a bit different because it is the only place that I've seen that shows how the server project / host can serve blazor component pages rather than just MVC / razor.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, Agree re. choice of Client/Server boundary and ability to protect IP via Web Api.  Another motivation I had was that I find Blazor Sever much quicker to develop and I wanted the option to be able to take advantage of that while still using WASM.  I'm now in the process of testing operation.  I'm interested in whether there are any limitations in this implementation   I certainly would be interested in any thoughts you have.

Comment: I do all my development work on Server.  As you say it's far quicker, less error prone and more informative.   How/where you host the application is just an endpoint.  The only code in that project should be stuff specific to the endpoint and the program.cs to build the application.  You have to be a bit careful with libraries, principally keeping the controllers away from any library used by the WASM project.  You can make API calls from a Server project so you can test both the full server and API data pipelines in server.  Authentication?

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, I'm wrapping my head around authentication at present.  I'll lock the server pages down so they can only be called by the wasm client.  I was planning on using an iframe in the WASM component to surface the server page, but I'm still working out how to pass the authenticated credentials to the iframe.  I'm using AzureAD with MSAL.

Comment: I'm considering whether I can just pass a bearer token that the Api receives or whether I will need to use another token.. Must admit I'm still not sure whether I'll be able to achieve everything I want to with just the Client and Server projects and authentication may beat me in the end.   I studied your https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo repository that provides a strategy for breaking out functionality into many libraries.  I may be forced to go down that route eventually, but want to explore this relatively simple scenario a bit more first

Comment: Demo is in a bit of flux at the moment.  I've been working on some new ideas to make the whole code base a lot more efficient.  Smaller code footprint, less CPU cycles and therefore greener.  I've bookmarked this answer and will post if I have some ideas on the authentication.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED ANSWER SHOWING FULL MIX AND MATCH BETWEEN WASM AND SERVER PROJECTS - INCLUDING AzureAD AUTHENTICATION**
Following discussion with @MrC aka Shaun Curtis in comments, I undertook to add Authentication using AzureAD to the solution and it proved to be quite a bit more involved that I expected.

I have prepared a Github repository for the solution at:  https://github.com/gwruck/Blazor_WASM_Server

There was a fair bit to getting everything to work - especially for the authentication, but it ended up being not too much of a change from the base template from visual studio for the Blazor WASM hosted solution.

Following is a screenshot of the solution and I'd encourage you to have a look.
[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER SHOWING DETAILED INSTRUCTIONS FOR HOSTING Blazor Pages on the Server project**

1. Create a new Blazor Web Assembly Solution (WASM).  Choose the hosted option.  You should have three projects in the solution (Client, Server and Shared)

[image]

2. Create a new Blazor Server Project.  We will use this as a dummy template to make it easier to implement the Server Pages in the WASM project.  Copy the highlighted folders / files into the WASM.Server project.

[image]

**In the Server Project**

1. Update namespaces / references etc. in all of the imported files.  I also perform the following renames to avoid clashes with the WASM project:

   - wwwroot/css folder --> wwwroot/svr-css
   - wwwroot/favicon.ico --> wwwroot/svr-favicon.ico
   - App.razor --> ServerApp.razor  (then update the reference to this file in _Layout.cshtml)
2. Change the @page paths (including _Host) to have a prefix eg.  @page "/counter" --> @page "svr/counter"

[image]

3. Update the ServerApp.razor file

[image]

4. Update the _Layout File for references to the new svr-css folder location

[image]

5. Update Program.cs as follows (Note: I couldn't get the code formatting to work, so if you want the text of this code, go to the Github link at the end of this answer)
   [image]

[image]

Following is the final structure of the Server project.

[image]

Then navigate to the app url [https://localhost:7073/] you should start on the WASM home page:

[image]

If you then navigate to the /srv url [https://localhost:7073/srv] you should see the Blazor Server home page from the dummy Blazor Server app that we used to create this sample.

[image]

Here is a link to a Github repo.  https://github.com/gwruck/BlazorWasmMixedwithServerPages

There are quite a few other things that you will need to implement for a production app, including authentication and how to get a seamless experience for users navigating between the WASM and Server pages.  It will also be necessary to consider other paths within the Server project (eg. /api etc.) for the MapWhen section of the Program file to ensure that you implement the correct behavior for these paths.

For navigation, my plan is to use an iframe in the WASM app to call and display the Server app pages so that from the users perspective, it is all one app, with consistent layouts etc.

For authentication, I use Azure AD and expect that this may be a bit of a challenge as I also use the Server project to host a Web Api.  If it proves to be difficult, I will add another post.